# after reading a file as text i can't remake a file from it

Tags: javascript, filereader, data-uri

i have a file a image/png file i need to read it with the `FileReader` api and then make a `file` or `blob` from the text the problem here is when i try to make a file the data seems to be corrupted i tried to read the data as text after reading the file as `dataURL` and there is difference i need a way to make the text from the `FileReader.readAsText` match the one from `decoded dataURL by atob`

```js
let inp = document.querySelector("input")

async function read(file,type) { 
    let reader = new FileReader
    reader[type](file)

    return new Promise((res) => { 
        reader.addEventListener("load",_ => { 
            res(reader.result)
        })
    })
}

function decodeDataUrl(dataurl) { 
   return atob(dataurl.split(',')[1])
}

inp.addEventListener("input",async _ => { 
    let [file] = inp.files

    let dataURL = await read(file,"readAsDataURL")
    let text = decodeDataUrl(dataURL)
    console.log({text,length: text.length});

    text = await read(file,"readAsText")
    console.log({text,length: text.length});
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file">
</body>
</html>
```

and here is a screenshot after testing the code with file[image]

notes:

1. i don't want any library or framework for that so no jquery
2. don't present another way for dealing with files or blob best than that i know i can use another ways to manage files data better than read it as text by `FileReader.readAsText` but i don't have control over this point
3. don't mind my bad english

Comment: If the function returns a promise explicitly, you shouldn't declare it `async`. That wraps the promise in another promise.

Comment: A PNG file isn't a text file. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I'm sending the image to my server by using formData api and it seems to be converting the data to text and in the server i need to turn it back to file/blob

Comment: To read the png file as text you probably need to specify the encoding as **Latin-1** (ISO-8859-1) (instead of utf-8), to obtain a "binary string" of file content in the lower 8 bits of a UTF16 string characters, which could then be converted to a base64 string to match the URL string. Even so there are more modern methods of uploading a file, using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file) for example. How are you decoding the upload on the server?

Comment: If you read the file as text using the default encoding of utf-8, **you can no longer reconstruct the binary content of the file** - it has been corrupted. I don't understand point 2 of the post that starts with "don't present another way for dealing with files ...": it doesn't actually make sense in English.  You may have an X-Y problem, meaning you want to know how to proceed from where you are, but in reality you need to take a step back and choose another path.

Comment: @traktor i not good in English but what i mean is don't tell me to not read the file as text or use the --- library or read it as dataURL or something like this becuse i don't my problem not on how to make the project work this problem i tried to deal use but i couldn't so I'm asking if there a way i don't know about i rarely deal with problems like that so I'm not fully aware of problems like that

Comment: An image file is binary data, you would use [`readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) to read it. However these are relatively new API-s, uploading images to a server do not need them. Also, there's no trace in the code of any upload attempt.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1 - using `readFileAsText`**

```
const binaryString = await read(file, "latin1");
```

where bytes from the file are inserted in `binaryString` as 8 bit character codes.

`binaryString` can be converted to a base64 encoded string using

```
const base64String = btoa(binaryString);
```

---

**Answer 2 - using `formData`**

This is best covered in formData method examples on MDN:

1. Using [`formData.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set#examples)

   > ```
   > formData.set("userpic", myFileInput.files[0], "chris.jpg");
   > ```
2. To upload multiple files using the same named form field, use the `formData.append` method instead.

Comment: imm the problem is after i read the file as text in utf-8 i can't return it as binary

Comment: As my second question comment said: you **can't** read the file as utf-8 text and  get the binary content back. _Wanting to (or being told to) will not change that it can't be done._ This means you _do_ have an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)  problem